# Single workflow with different behavior depends on states

Tags: apex, workflow

I got a requirement that I have to build a single workflow and depends on different states the behavior of workflow has to be different.
Is there a way we can achieve like this in Salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple *behaviours* for different *states* using a single Workflow. You need to use Process Builder for that.

In programming language, Workflow is analogous to a single IF block:

```
IF (conditions) THEN (statements)
```

whereas Process Builder can have multiple IF blocks:

```
IF (conditions 1) THEN (statements)
ELSE IF (conditions 2) THEN (statements)
ELSE IF (conditions 3) THEN (statements)
...
```